# $q$-analogue of $\sum_{k=0}^n \, {n \choose k} = 2^n $

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, q-analogs

Is there a $q$-analogue of the formula $\sum_{k=0}^n \, {n \choose k} = 2^n $ in terms of the $q$-binomial coefficient ${n \choose k}_q$ and $(2^n)_q=(1+q)...(1+q^n)$?

Comment: Do you mean something like this?  If $$(1+x)_q^n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+q^kx),$$ then $$(1+x)_q^n=\sum_{k=0}^nq^{\frac{k(k-1)}{2}}\binom{n}{k}_q x^k.$$  I have seen this somewhere, but I can't remember.  I will come back with a reference if I figure out.

Comment: yes, thats exactly what I meant, thx!

Comment: From the Wikipedia page we see: $$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+q^kt)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}q^{k(k-1)/2}\binom{n}{k}_qt^k$$ Setting $t=q$ gets a formula. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient?wprov=sfti1

Comment: Jonathan Azose’s 2007 Harvey Mudd College undergraduate thesis, [*Applications of the q-Binomial Coefficients to Counting Problems*](https://scholarship.claremont.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1194&context=hmc_theses), introduces a nice combinatorial interpretation of the q-binomial coefficients and in Section 2.3 uses it to prove this quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

The most natural analog is $\sum_{k=0}^{n}q^{k}\binom{n}{k}_{q^2}=(1+q)(1+q^2)\dots(1+q^n)$. 
If you can read German you find a proof in https://homepage.univie.ac.at/johann.cigler/preprints/id2.pdf. (2.16).